# WPF Textbox Text Update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

(I know there are questions asked about this, but as you can see in my question, I think I tried the solutions without success).

Simply, I'm trying to bind the text in my textbox with the view model.

Code in view model:

```
public class MainClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 ... 
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;         
protected void onPropertyChanged ​(string propertyName)   
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
}
private string _Stuff ="Original Value";
public string Stuff {
    get { return _Stuff;  }
    private set {
        if (value != _Stuff)
        {
            _Stuff = value;
            Method();
            OnPropertyChanged("Stuff");
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Stuff,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</TextBox>
```

Now, the binding does work one way - that is, when the XAML is first initialized, the text box is populated with "Original Value". But when I change the value in the box (even when I lose focus on it), the field isn't updated (I can tell because, firstly, Method isn't called, and also when I use the debugger I can see the value hasn't changed).

What part am I doing incorrectly?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the context is set in the controller, and is apparently working, because as I said, the binding is working one way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem might be here:

```
public string Stuff {
    get { return _Stuff;  }
    private set {
        if (value != _Stuff)
        {
            _Stuff = value;
            Method();
            OnPropertyChanged("Stuff");
        }
    }
}
```

Your setter is `private`, remove the `private` and it should work.

Comment: I hope you have a fantastic day, because you just saved mine

Comment: Thank you and happy to help! :-)